# How to replace a tuple in sorted list of tuples basing on first value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace, tuples

I am new to python, and I'm looking for help with solving the following problem

I need to create a sorted list of tuples/dictionaries basing on provided data. Then when new data is provided, and has the same first key, I want to replace it's value with new one. To be more clear I will give example... Imagine I have data, which looks as follows :

`data = [(1, 100), (2, 200), (4, 400), (7, 900)]`

Then I have new entry from user for example:

`(4,500)`

So, now I want to replace this tuple with `(4,400)` to this one with `(4,500)`. I know that tuples are immutable, thus I don't want to update anything, just erase previous one basing on the key (here: 4) and replace it with new tuple.

So far I used a class from another stack which insert every new entry (tuple) in a sorted way to a list of tuples, and I want it to stay this way, because further I need to calculate closest lower and higher number to provided one in case if its not in a list.

My code looks as follows:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left


class KeyWrapper:
    def __init__(self, iterable, key):
        self.it = iterable
        self.key = key

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.key(self.it[i])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.it)

data = [(1, 100), (2, 200), (4, 400), (7, 900)]
data.sort(key=lambda c: c[0])

newcol = (3, 500)

bslindex = bisect_left(KeyWrapper(data, key=lambda c: c[0]), newcol[0])
data.insert(bslindex, newcol)
```

The output looks as follows:

`[(1,100),(2,200),(3,500),(4,400),(7,900)]`

And providing new variable for ex. `newcols2 = (3,600)`, basing on first element of a tuple (here 3)
I want to be output like:

`[(1,100),(2,200),(3,600),(4,400),(7,900)]`

Comment: Why not to use OrderedDict? Your solution is very complicated and strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
data = [(1, 100), (2, 200), (4, 400), (7, 900)]
new = (4, 500)

# Filter out matching
data = [i for i in data if i[0] != new[0]]
# Add the new
data.append(new)
# Re-sort
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
```